# node escpos printer cut function not working, I am using STAR printer

Tags: node.js, escpos

I am using node escpos for printing ticket. Here is my code snippet.

I am just following the sample code posted here https://www.npmjs.com/package/escpos. I already tried cut("full") and cut("partial"). Still not working

```
        const device = new escpos.USB();
        const options = { encoding: "GB18030" /* default */ }

        const printer = new escpos.Printer(device, options);
        device.open(function () {

            console.log('Printing...');

            printer
                .font('a')
                .align('ct')
                .style('bu')
                .size(1, 1)
                .text('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
                .text('敏捷的棕色狐狸跳过懒狗')
                .barcode('1234567', 'EAN8')
                .qrimage('https://github.com/song940/node-escpos', function (err) {
                    this.cut();
                    this.close();
                });

            return "OK";
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return err + "";
    }
```

The code actually prints the text but the problem is the printer cut function is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The print position must be at the beginning of a line to execute the paper cut command.

In the print request of the QR code, isn't it new line?

After printing a QR code, perform a line feed (LF), and then perform a paper cut.

The following is part of the detailed paper cut for the ESCPOS command. (GS V m)

> This command is effective only when processed at the top of the line when standard mode is
>   being used.

---

Then it will take about a second to cut the paper.

Is it all right to close the port immediately after sending the command?

Please try inserting a delay before closing.

---

Basically, is it a hardware model with a auto paper cutter?

[ESC/POS® Mode Command Specifications](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/mannualfolder/escpos_cm_en.pdf)

Comment: I've tried adding this.control("LF") before the cut, still not working. Maybe it only works on EPSON printers?

Comment: How about trying various patterns such as text printing and paper cutting only?