# Node ESCPOS printer text alignments are not working for STAR printer

Tags: node.js, printing, escpos

I am using [ESCPOS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/escpos) library for printing menu items using SP700 star printer. Data is coming properly in print but align and style properties are not working.

My code snippet:

```
    var network = new escpos.Network(printerData.IpAddress);
    const options = { encoding: "GB18030" /* default */ }  // encoding is optional
    printer = new escpos.Printer(network, options);
        network.open(function (error, device) {
            printer
            .font('A')
            .align('ct')
            .style('NORMAL')
            .size(1, 1)
            ;
            
        printer.align('ct')
        printer.print("property- align: 'ct'");
        printer.align('CT')
        printer.print("property- align: 'CT'");
        printer.align('CENTER')
        printer.style('bu');
        printer.print("property- align: 'CENTER' & style: 'bu'");
        printer.style('B');
        printer.print("style: 'B'");
        printer.print("Date: ");
        printer.style('normal');
        printer.print("property- style: 'NORMAL'");
        printer.style('NORMAL');
        printer.println(printDataHolder.printData.date);
    });
```

Here I have added some dummy text to check with different property values like 'ct', 'CT', 'CENTER' for center alignment and 'bu', 'B' for bold style but all text are getting printed in left alignment and normal text.

Below is the print:

[image]

Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For example, have you tried to see if the node-escpos test script works? [node-escpos/test/test.js](https://github.com/song940/node-escpos/blob/v3/test/test.js) There is another article like this, and my answer hasn't solved it, but in the question, it seems that the centering etc. worked well except for the paper cut. [node escpos printer cut function not working, I am using STAR printer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57282212/9014308) Why don't you look for other samples and try them like that?

Comment: Yes, I am referring [escpos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/escpos) and using the same alignment and style properties given in that [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57282212/node-escpos-printer-cut-function-not-working-i-am-using-star-printer). It's working for other printers except the star printer. Here I am connecting through network IP that is the only difference.

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked your written printer model information.

Star Micronics' Dot Impact Printer has many unique ESC/POS commands, one of which is alignment settings.

`ESC a n` is for standard ESC/POS, but `ESC GS a n` for Star Micronics Dot Impact Printer.

EPSON
[ESC a](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=58)

```
[Name]
Select justification
[Format]
ASCII   ESC  a  n
Hex     1B  61  n
Decimal 27  97  n
```

Please refer to this specification and define your own bytes array data according to the command supported by the printer.
[Dot Impact Printer STAR Command Specifications Rev. 1.91](https://www.starmicronics.com/support/Mannualfolder/dot_star_cm_en.pdf)
Page 3-32

```
ESC GS a n
[Name] Specify position alignment
[Code] ASCII       ESC GS a  n
       Hexadecimal 1B  1D 61 n
       Decimal     27  29 97 n
```

Answer (score 0):

please try chaining code like :

```js
const SerialPort = require("serialport");
const escpos = require("escpos");
escpos.SerialPort = require("escpos-serialport");

...

const options = { encoding: "your language encoding" };
const device = new escpos.SerialPort('COM1', { baudRate: 9600 }); // example 'COM1', 9600
  const printer = new escpos.Printer(device, options);
  device.open(function (err: any) {
    printer
     .align("CT") // align center
     .style("B") // font weight bold
     .size(0.1, 0.1) // text size
     .text("Your big test text")
     .size(0.01, 0.01)
     .text("Your small test text")
     .cut()
     .close();
  }
```

Or, if you re-declare it, try re-declaring "CT" and "encoding" in the first part, and I think it might work.

```js
    printer
     .align("CT") // align center
     .style("B") // font weight bold
     .size(0.1, 0.1) // text size
     .text("Your big test text");

   printer
     .encode("your language encoding")
     .align("CT") // align center
     .style("NORMAL")
     .size(0.01, 0.01)
     .text("Your small test text")
     .cut()
     .close();
```

It may be helpful to check the path below.
`node_modules > escpos > index.js`
`node_modules > escpos > commands.js`